# Error Failed building wheel for pillow while installing on Windows

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install `Pillow` on `python 3.10` using command `pip install Pillow` and it occurs `ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow` below:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Mohamad\PycharmProjects\faracode_project> pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-10.0.1.tar.gz (50.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for Pillow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [198 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\QoiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310\PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'renovate.json'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext


      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 988, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 88, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "<string>", line 811, in build_extensions
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\PycharmProjects\faracode_project\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\PycharmProjects\faracode_project\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\PycharmProjects\faracode_project\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xk8l2iu8\pillow_9f3d6b155be8444f883eaa9ca76d54dd\_custom_build\backend.py", line 53, in build_wheel
          return super().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings, metadata_directory)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xk8l2iu8\pillow_9f3d6b155be8444f883eaa9ca76d54dd\_custom_build\backend.py", line 47, in run_setup
          return super().run_setup(setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Mohamad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vci27j8a\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 1005, in <module>
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

After some searches, I've tried:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pillow
```

But it didn't work and everything was just same as before.

Will be much appreciated if somebody help. I really need this to be solved.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is best to try another older version of pillow to see if that installs. to install an older version for example you can do: `pip install Pillow==1.0.0`

Comment: Actually I tried, but again it raises the ''ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow''

Comment: keep trying with different versions